# How do I use XProc as a copy filter in gradle?

Tags: gradle, marklogic, calabash, xproc, ml-gradle

I have an XQuery script that I want to run against all of the files in a gradle copy task as a filter.  I am looking at both XQJ and XProc.  Since there is a supported implementation of Calabash in ml-gradle, I decided to go that route.

Is there an example of using XProc as a filter in a gradle copy task?

Here is something that I used for a gradle task for generating xqDoc using the xqDoc java library.  I would like some help to do something similar, but using XProc as the filter.

```
class XQDocFilter extends BaseFilterReader {
  XQDocFilter(Reader input) {
    super(new StringReader(new org.xqdoc.MarkLogicProcessor().process(input.text)))
  }
}

task generateXQDocs(type: Copy) {
  into 'xqDoc'
  from 'src/main/ml-modules'
  include '**/*.xq*'
  rename { it - '.xq*' + '.xml' }
  includeEmptyDirs = false
  eachFile { println it }
  filter XQDocFilter
}
```

Comment: You mean that there is a supported implementation in *gradle*, not *ml-gradle*, correct? I don't see any reference to Calabash in ml-gradle. Assuming you were referring to https://github.com/ndw/xmlcalabash1-gradle ?

Comment: I am referring to Norm's Gradle implementation of XML Calabash.

Answer (score 1):

I added an XMLCalabashFilter class to xmlcalabash1-gradle starting in version 1.5.0.

Comment: Hello Norm,  Thank you.  I am looking forward to your feedback.  My alternative would to use XQJ and implement a filter.  I do not see a lot of support for XQL.

Comment: I find the gradle docs so hard to use. As near as I can tell, a filter applies to each line in the file. If that's the case, I'm not sure XProc 1.0 is going to be a good fit. I plan to make XProc 3.0 versions as well, and handling text in 3.0 is much easier.

Comment: The filter applies to each file.  If you look at the gradle task that I include above, It runs the filter against each XQuery source file identified and returns an xqDoc XML document.

Comment: So the Gradle documentation has failed me once again. Sigh. I'll look again. If you know where the BaseFileReader API is documented, feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check out `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.BaseFilterReader`. Check out the build.gradle at https://github.com/easymetahub/emh-marklogic-glossary

Comment: Also look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files

Comment: Ok. It seems to be possible. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Now blocked by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898982/how-does-the-gradle-runtime-configuration-for-a-task-differ-from-the-configurati

Comment: @LorenCahlander I just published version 1.5.0 of the xmlcalabash1-gradle extension which includes a filter. You'll find an example of how to use it in the repo in src/test/resources. Let me know if it works for you.